# Using dart web-ui (polymer) with ASP.NET MVC site, need help running as javascript

Tags: dart, dart-webui, polymer

I have a dart polymer project being served up by an ASP.NET MVC site.  The application page is actually a `cshtml` file that is in a different directory than the rest of the dart files.  Besides this, everything is laid out in an idiomatic fashion.  When running in Dartium, everything works great.  When I run as javascript, I get the message `boot.js only works in Dartium. Run the build.dart tool to compile a depolyable JavaScript version`.

This scenario seems like it will be difficult to accommodate.  Any ideas how I can get the application working as javascript while keeping it as a cshtml file served up by ASP.NET MVC?

Answer (score 3):

This is a known issue. Try using this version of `build.dart`:

```dart
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:polymer/component_build.dart';
import 'package:polymer/deploy.dart' as deploy;

void main() {
  build(new Options().arguments, ['web/index.html']).then((_) => deploy.main());
}
```

You might get a message about a missing index.html_bootstrap.dart.js file. Dart engineers are working on making all of this work more smoothly and you should soon be able to run the deploy script through the editor.

Meanwhile, there is a discussion of this very issue on the web-ui mailing list if anyone's interested:

https://groups.google.com/a/dartlang.org/d/msg/web-ui/mLsdykraJdA/k77QuP1T2_sJ

I'll update this answer when a better alternative to the current solution is implemented.

Comment: Thanks Shailen.  There is still an issue with running the build/deploy steps with a CSHTML file.  It predictably fails when it encounters Razor syntax.  I imagine this would be pretty difficult to accommodate.  For now, I've just made it a static HTML page.